# Separating posts from different post types from wp query

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Is there any way to separate posts from wp_query to multiple post types.Suppose i have a argument for wp_query that is `'post_types' => array('post', 'plays')`
Now after the query i get a bunch of results of posts from `post` and `plays` post types then how can i separate `posts` from `post` and `plays` ?

Answer (score 1):

Add it as an argument like so:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'type',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop when you are processing the items, you can use the post_type attribute to check for different post types

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        if($post->post_type=="post"){
            //Do something
        }
        elseif($post->post_type=="plays"){
            //Do something
        }
    } // end while
} // end if
```